# Create Custom Log in Event Viewer with C++

Tags: c++, logging, event-log, etw, event-viewer

I want to be able to create a custom log in event viewer (i.e. to create a custom node under "Application and Services Logs" in windows event viewer)

It is an easy task, if you use EventLog.CreateEventSource method: [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a.aspx#Y0) Its problem is that this method is only available from in the unmanaged code.

I'm wondering if there is any way I can do this in my Managed C++ code.

I'm currently using manifest-based ETW for logging. Is there anywhere in the manifest of the provider that I can set it?

Cheers,
Reza++

Comment: The link you posted refers to managed C++ code. Do you want the answer with unmanaged C++?